# applicationWillEnterForeground and storyboard check

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, usersession

I have a ios App where I used the storyboards.

I have a question: When the user return from background I will check if the user session is still valid. If this session is expired I would to send the user to login controller (second step on my storyboard)
How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have not tried anything because I do not know what would be the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

just do like this

pseudocode not a actual code

```
(void)applicationWillEnterForeground
{
if(sessionAvailable)
{
//do normal next working
}
else
{
LoginViewController *loginViewController=[self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithidentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loginViewController animates:YES];
}
}
```